# SimpleDateFormat changing timezone of date

Tags: java, date

```
Date mDate;
public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss Z";
String stringDate = "Thu, 21 Sep 2017 18:15:00 +0200";
final SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT,Locale.ENGLISH);
mDate = SDF.parse(stringDate);
```

```
stringDate = "Thu, 21 Sep 2017 18:15:00 +0200"
mDate result string representation = "Thu Sep 21 19:15:00 GMT+03:00 2017"
```

As you can see the time zone and hour changed, and i cant figure it out why.

The enviroment is android studio running on an android device.

I've tried to change `Locale`, `SDF.setTimeZone()` and some more different options, but the result is allways the same. 
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The `toString()` implementation of `Date` always renders string in the default time zone. It's the only thing it *can* do, since `Date` objects don't have a time zone. If you want the date value displayed in another time zone, you need to use a formatter with the appropriate zone.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is actually in the `Date` object that that just use a default timezone for all of it's `toString` method.

With help of Andreas found what i was looking for:

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+2")); // set whatever timezone you want.
    String resultString = df.format(mDate);
```

`resultString = 2017-09-21 18:15:00`

Comment: You should not be using these troublesome old classes at all, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. See the ThreeTenABP project for Android,p. Search Stack Overflow for class names Instant, ZoneId, ZonedDateTime, and DateTimeFormatter.